# How to change readonly property in category in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

In my *.h file I have `foo` property that is readonly.
I update that property win some other public method by using `_foo = _foo + 1;`

Now I have category on that *.h file.
I need to update `foo` property from category.

If I use `_foo` then I got `Use of undeclared identifier '_foo''`
If I use `self.foo = 5` then I got `Assignment to readonly property`

I know that I can fix this by setting `foo` property as readwrite, but I would like to avoid that.

**Question**
How to solve it ?
Also is it possible to set property as readonly from outside the class, but as readwrite from within the class and category ?
 That would solve this problem.

Comment: AFAIK you can re-declare the property as `(readwrite)` and implement a setter. If this does not work (it surely works in a class extension, but I'm not sure about categories), then you can always use KVC and `setValue:forKey:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could declare the property's backing instance variable in the header file as well, so the compiler can see it in the category:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    int _foo;
}
@property (readonly) int foo;
@end
```

Explicitly declare that this variable will be used to back the property (for safety only):

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize foo = _foo;
...
@end
```

And then referencing `_foo` in the category should work fine:

```
@implementation MyClassCategory

- (void)someMethod
{
    _foo++;
}
```

Comment: Better to declare the ivar in a private extension whose header the category's implementation imports. Then the ivar is still private.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah good idea; in a file called `MyClass_Private.h`, perhaps?

Comment: I have not tested this, but it look like it is easier to just put property readwrite and be careful what you do.  Why do I need to do `@synthesize foo = _foo;` ?

Comment: @WebOrCode Just to be overly sure the correct backing instance variable is used and it acts as documentation.  It's completely redundant, however.